# JShint not working in any text editor

Tags: sublimetext3, jshint, adobe-brackets, sublimelinter

JShint will not run in any text editor I have (Sublime Text 3 and Brackets). JShint is installed globally on my system. SublimeLinter and SublimeLinter-jshint are installed in Sublime Text 3. JShint is installed in Brackets and the added:

```
"language": {
    "javascript": {
        "linting.prefer": "JSHint",
        "linting.usePreferredOnly": true
    }
}
```

to the preference file and .brackets.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Brackets, you've already done the right thing with the config lines in the JSON preferences file, but it still needs an Extension installed to work.

So, open up the Extension Manager (File > Extension Manager) and search for "JSHint" and install the JSHint Extension (I used the one by Raymond Camden).